# Showing a group is not the internal direct product of cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Question:
>   Let$ G={3^{a}6^{b}10^{c}}$ under multiplication and $H={3^{a}6^{b}12^{c}}$
>   For all $a,b,c \in R$
>   Prove that$ G=<3>x <6>x <10> $ and H is not $<3>x <6>x <12> $

I should be able to solve the first part. What I did was basically listing down 'all' the elements in G then generalizing it to a cyclic group and then utilising the property of Internal direct product.

However, the second part is extremely problematic. I am unable to understand how H should not be equal to the internal direct product of the cyclic group in the question. Should H be a subgroup? Seems like a poorly worded question.

Hints are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ integers? What's $R$?

Answer (score 1):

You can recover $a,b,c$ from $3^{a}6^{b}10^{c}=2^{b+c} 3^{a+b} 5^c$.

This means that $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to G$ defined by $(a,b,c) \mapsto 3^{a}6^{b}10^{c}$ is a bijection.

You cannot recover $a,b,c$ from $3^{a}6^{b}12^{c}=2^{b+2c}3^{a+b+c}$.

This means that $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to H$ defined by $(a,b,c) \mapsto 3^{a}6^{b}12^{c}$ is surjective but not injective.

For instance, both $(0,2,0)$ and $(1,0,1)$ go to $36$.

Comment: What is the sufficient condition here?